I need query address on multichain, Is there a way to use the multichain portfolio as an API?

hello
how can i query with API multichain portofolia on etherscan or bscscan?
Unfortunately, there is no such query type among the APIs, but I need this type of query.
When I try to get it with curl, I am blocked by cloudflare.
Does anyone have any ideas or know a similar API?
